# iOS: Is it ok to hide the purchase button after a non-consumable purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've searched SO and the web and Apple's docs on in-app purchasing, and have not found an answer to this question. If I somehow missed the answer, my apologies.

I'm writing an iOS game that will have a single non-consumable in-app purchase to unlock the full game. The purchase and restore buttons are on a separate (settings) screen from the game screen. When the user makes a successful purchase, I set a flag in UserDefaults. Once that has happened, the purchase and restore buttons are unnecessary.

Is it ok to hide the purchase and restore buttons after a successful purchase so that they don't clutter up the settings screen? Or is that a violation of Apple's guidelines, or maybe just frowned upon?

It seems to me that there shouldn't be a problem with that. As long as my UserDefaults flag is true, I know that the purchase was made and the game should be unlocked, so there's no need for either the purchase or the restore button. And if, after making the purchase, the user deletes the app and reinstalls, my UserDefaults flag will be false so I will show the buttons and the user can hit the restore button in order to get the full game back.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It’s probably fine. What I do is, I only show the whole purchase dialog if the user tries to do something that requires it. So after the purchase the user cannot summon that dialog at all. The restore logic is exactly as you’ve described.